# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout Error 17

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter

Keep getting the following error:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout.
```

As you can see below I have the adapter set but in the `OnDataChange()` Method I think this may be the issue as it needs to be in the `OnCreate()` method but I cannot seem to fix it.

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_judge);

        RecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    DatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UploadClass upload = 
       postSnapshot.getValue(UploadClass.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }
            Adapter = new ImageAdapter(JudgeActivity.this, mUploads);
            ProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            RecyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
         }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 0):

You set the adapter but did so too late. The view is loaded with no adapter because you're waiting for Firebase.

Ideally you should set your adapter initially, so remove the `mUploads` paramater in the constructor.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) find...
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    ...
}
```

Initially the adapter will have no data - but the RecyclerView will have an adapter solving your problem.

You can set the data later, if you store an instance of your adapter you can simply:

`adapter.setUploads(mUploads)`

in your Firebase call.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was just wondering where is the .setUploads() coming from? and also what do you mean by Firebase call?

Comment: setUploads is a function you should write, I just used a common naming convention. That function should set the uploads in the adapter. The firebase call is the onDataChange method

Comment: I have made these changes and i'm still getting the same error?